# How to define a dynamic range using as reference a cell that changes columns/rows

Tags: excel, vba

[the highlighted area is the range I need to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEJuq.png)
I have an Excel file that me and my team use to harvest reviews from GP for our apps. The thing is, I want to improve this excel by adding some buttons using VBA Code, to automatize some weekly tasks such as clearing the whole contents of the sheets and make it a fresh one for a fresh week. I need to know how do I refer to a range of cells knowing the following: the start of the range is always the same cell, but the end cell is changing every day. The cell below the end cell is always the same value. How do I define that range to start from A1, let's say, to the cell above this constant (which today is C3, but tomorrow might be C6?

Comment: You should start by watching this video:[Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: So you are trying to find the last row used and delete everything? Is the last column changing too? If not, what is the last column?

Comment: `The cell below the end cell...` this is confusing. I'm interpreting the `end cell` as the last cell, so what exactly is below it? Does this change the problem from our end? You also say starting from `A1... to the cell above this`. Typically, we wouldn't say anything is "above" the first row, but rather below it. My point is that your question is confusing. If you are having a hard time explaining it, upload some example photos

Comment: I attached a photo to better explain what I need. the encircled area in the photo is the range I need to define. In the photo I posted, I need range C268:F277 to be selected. Each day, new rows are inserted in that range or extracted, so the range needs to expand or contract accordingly, but select only that range, the other contents of the sheet must remain intact. More precisely, I want to make a reset button, that deletes the content of White cells, basically

Comment: One mention: there is a range like this, having the same columns (different rows, though) for each day of the week, so last row method probably won't work. I thought of using offset but I cannot seem to define the proper height of each selection.

Answer (score 0):

This will use `Column A` to determine where the last used row (`LR`). We will use `Row 1` to determine where the last used column is (`LC`)

We then clear the contents & formats from `A1` (top left of range corner) to `LC:LR` (bottom right of range corner)

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Clear()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- UPDATE SHEET NAME

Dim LR As Long 'Last Row
Dim LC As Long 'Last Column

LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LC = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LR, LC)).ClearContents
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LR, LC)).ClearFormats

End Sub
```